# Is it possible to create a contact attribute to store time in contact builder?

Tags: journeybuilder, contact, contactbuilder

I'm trying to add an attribute to store time. And then start journey on that specific time. Is it possible in Journey Builder?

Currently I can only see data type `Date, Text, Number, Boolean etc` But I want to store time and start journey the base of that time.`

Or is there any other way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

What if you use filters to the entry data extension? And only the records whose 'time' field is the one you want will be injected. That Data Extension can be refresh periodically based on your needs.

Comment: Thank you @fromero for your quick response. Actually I'm new to salesforce. Your answer is not clear for me how to do what you have described.

It would be very helpful if you explain it little more

Comment: @MuhammadAwais if the entry of the Journey is a Data Extension, one of the steps to configure it is 'Filter Contacts'. In that step I suggest to apply the filter (when the date based on an existing field in the Data Extension is 'XX:XX:XX') then the records will be injected in the Journey. The Journey will be triggered based on an Automation. So, when the Data Extension is refreshed in the Automation, the Journey will be triggered automatically.